# Does have Mathematica a built-in function for write Dirac delta in spherical coordinate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, coordinate-transformation

It has been appeared $\delta(\mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2)$ in one of my integrals which I have to calculate. The differentials of the integral are $dr_1d\theta_1d\phi_1 dr_2d\theta_2d\phi_2$ So I need to write this Dirac delta in spherical coordinates. I just found
$$
\delta(\mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2)=\frac{1}{r_1^2}\delta(r_1 -r_2)\delta(\cos\theta_1 -\cos\theta_2)\delta(\phi_1 -\phi_2) 
$$
by searching the web, but I'm not sure about that. How can I deal with this problem?

**Addendum**

This is my code and I try to calculate the result of  `ep`. Note that by `DirecDelta[re-rp]` I mean $\delta(\mathbf r_e-\mathbf r_p)$ namely vectors of $r_e$ and $r_p$ beacaue I didn't know how to write them in my code (spirit of my question)!

```
mp = 1836;
\[Omega] = 10^-2;
me = 1;
M = mp + me;
{\[Alpha], \[Beta]} = \
{0.99930605221867707665950320006231777369976043701171875`50., 
   0.00014974969686706935865193324186606105286045931279659271240234375\
`50.};
\[Gamma] = 1/2*M*\[Omega];
norm = 2.12025232778742133718363166442892649864;
a = SetPrecision[2.35, 50];
b = SetPrecision[2.4, 50];
c = SetPrecision[3.2, 50];
intrE[r_, re_] := (
  E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + r \[Beta])) (E^(-((
      2 (me re + mp (-r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2)) - 
     E^(-((2 (me re + mp (r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2))) M^2)/(
  4 mp (me + mp) \[Gamma]);
intE[re_?NumericQ] := (2*\[Pi])/re norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrE[r, re], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
intrp[r_, rp_] := (
  E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + r \[Beta])) (E^(-((
      2 (mp rp + me (-r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2)) - 
     E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2))) M^2)/(
  4 me (me + mp) \[Gamma]);
intP[rp_?NumericQ] := (2*\[Pi])/rp norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrp[r, rp], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];



ep = -NIntegrate[(
   re^2*rp^2*intE[re]*intP[rp]*
    DiracDelta[re - rp] Sin[\[Theta]e] Sin[\[Theta]p])/(
   a - b*Sqrt[intE[re]*intP[rp]] + c *intE[re]*intP[rp]), {\[Theta]e, 
    0, \[Pi]}, {\[Theta]p, 0, \[Pi]}, {re, 0, \[Infinity]}, {rp, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {\[Phi]e, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Phi]p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Comment: The product  $a(x)\delta(x)$ is defined only for infinitely differentiable functions, but  $\frac{1}{r_1^2}$ has the singularity at the origin.

Comment: @user64494 This statement is not true, look at `Integrate[
 DiracDelta[x] Which[x^2 < b^2, Exp[b^2/(b^2 - x^2)], True, 
   0], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> b > 0]==E`

Comment: @UlrichNumann: THe LHS of $$ \delta(\mathbf r_1 -\mathbf r_2)=\frac{1}{r_1^2}\delta(r_1 -r_2)\delta(\cos\theta_1 -\cos\theta_2)\delta(\phi_1 -\phi_2)$$ makes sense if $r_1=0$, but the RHS does not.

Comment: Concerning Addendum, I'd like to quote the documentation to`DiracDelta` "Numerical routines will typically miss the contributions from measures at single points".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration `Integrate[\[Delta][...]dV`  about the infinite sphere must evaluate to `1`!

Test of your formula doesn't evaluate to one, but for the modified approach

$\delta (r-\text{r0},\theta -\text{$\theta $0},\phi -\text{$\phi $0})=\frac{\csc (\theta ) \tan (\text{$\theta $0}) \delta
   (\theta -\text{$\theta $0}) \delta (r-\text{r0}) \delta (\phi -\text{$\phi $0})}{r^2} $

the integration gives

```
sol=Integrate[ DiracDelta[r - r0]/(r^2 Sin[\[Theta]])DiracDelta[\[Phi] - \[Phi]0] DiracDelta[ \[Theta] - \[Theta]0 ]/Cot[\[Theta]0]  r^2 Cos[\[Theta]] 
, {r, 0,Infinity}, {\[Theta], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
Assumptions -> {r0 > 0, 0 < \[Phi] < 2 Pi, -Pi/2 < \[Theta] < Pi/2,Element[{r0, \[Theta]0, \[Phi]0}, Reals]} ]

(*UnitStep[\[Pi] - 2 \[Theta]0, \[Pi]/2 + \[Theta]0, 2 \[Pi] - \[Phi]0, \[Phi]0]*)

Plot3D[sol, {\[Phi]0, 0, 2 Pi}, {\[Theta]0, -Pi/2, Pi/2},AxesLabel -> {\[Phi]0, \[Theta]0} ]
```

[image]

The result equals `1` for `0 < \[Phi]0 < 2 Pi, -Pi/2 < \[Theta]0 < Pi/2`.

**addendum/modified**

The added  integral `ep==...` contains    `DiracDelta["re" -"rp"]` which stands for the vectorform of `DiracDelta` (see first part of the question)

It must be substituted by

`dirac = DiracDelta[re - rp]/re^2  DiracDelta[\[Phi]e - \[Phi]p] DiracDelta[\[Theta]e - \\[Theta]p]/( Sin[\[Theta]e] Cot[\[Theta]p])`

Knowing `Integrate[...DiracDelta[x - y],{x,0,Infinity}, {y,0,Infinity}]= Integrate[... /.x->y,  {y,0,Infinity}]` the  integration can be partially executed.  The integral can be divided into three parts

```
ep = -NIntegrate[ (re^2*rp^2*intE[re]*intP[rp]*1/re^2)/(a - b*Sqrt[intE[re]*intP[rp]] + c*intE[re]*intP[rp])  /.re -> rp  , {rp, 0, \[Infinity]}]*
NIntegrate[1 , {\[Phi]p, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]*
NIntegrate[1/( Sin[\[Theta]e] Cot[\[Theta]p])Sin[\[Theta]e] Sin[\[Theta]p] /. \[Theta]e -> \[Theta]p, {\[Theta]p, - Pi/2, \[Pi]/2}]    
(*-2.09081 *)
```

Comment: Can you give the definition of "the infinite sphere "? I have never met it. TIA.

Comment: Perhaps: Sphere with radius ->Infinity

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks a lot but I didn't understand how it works for my integral?! I have $r_1$ and $r_2$, can explain more or it is better to I add my explicit forms of my integrals in the question?

Comment: @Wisdom That would be helpful. In my formula I named the sphere coordinates `r, \[Phi], \[Theta]` and fixed point `r0, \[Phi]0, \[Theta]0`. But  I would only expect the differentials `dr  d\[Phi] d\[Theta]`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks please see the addendum.

Comment: @Wisdom Only the integral contains a `DiracDelta` ?  I'll modify my answer

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, it appears one time inside the `ep` integral. Many thanks

Comment: @Wisdom You're welcome! See my modified answer, hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks but the Dirac delta inside my integral includes vectors of $r_e$ and $r_p$ not scalar ones! I had written this point in the addendum. For this reason I was looking for a way to write dirac delta in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Wisdom but your code ` Integrate[...,{re,0,Infinity},{rp,0,Infinity}]` uses scalars `re,rp`???

Comment: Because I didn't know how to write vectors inside dirac delta in my code!

Comment: @Wisdom Look at my modified answer.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you so much. you helped me a lot. Can you give me a reference for your two last paragraphs? I mean `it must be ...` and `knowing...` because I'm not an expert in Mathematics and don't know these points. Thanks again.

Comment: @Wisdom See [Weisstein Mathworld Deltafunction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html), especially equation (2).

Comment: @UlrichNeumann many thanks. I'll check it out. it. god bless you.

Comment: @Wisdom Hope it helps!